# Адаптивная верстка уже обязательна или все еще по желанию?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Не совсем ясно с "*адаптивной версткой*". Ведь теперь чаще просматривают сайты с мобильного устройства - значит надо это учитывать **всегда**. Если с планшетами нет особых проблем, то на сматфонах требуется "*отзывчивая верстка*" (на медиа запросах).

Просто я считаю, что нельзя не думать как сайт будет работать на маленьком экране. Я пока еще учусь, но мне не понятно надо ли говорить заказчику, что на смартфоне будет не удобно пользоваться сайтом?

Comment: Определяется целями и бюджетом.

Comment: "*мне не понятно надо ли говорить заказчику, что на смартфоне будет не удобно пользоваться сайтом*" - КО докладывает: заказчику нужно говорить то, что целесообразно в каждом конкретном случае. Желательно - предварительно посчитав свою выгоду и перспективы сотрудничества с этим заказчиком.

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто. С вас спросят адаптивность верстки? Вам за неё заплатят? Делайте. Если нет - не делайте. Цените свое время и свой труд. А также время и труд всех ваших коллег.